# Is my rational function process for calculating tan(x) correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, rational-functions

I was bored in my Algebra 2 class and wanted to try to illustrate the tan(x) function as an infinite summation of rational functions.

I recalled that the solution to a rational function's numerator is equivalent to the roots of the function. The denominator's solution is the vertical asymptote(s). Since tan(x) has infinite roots and asymptotes, if I expressed it as a rational function it'd be infinitely long. My teacher suggested just using an infinite summation of rational functions, so I did that instead.

The first thing I did was set up the numerator and denominator so that they could each equal the corresponding roots and asymptotes; since it's (sorta? kinda? maybe) an even function, I just used variations of $x\pm \pi$ for both sides. Given that all roots of tan(x) are whole multiples of pi and all asymptotes are odd multiples of pi/2, I came up with the following equation (I hate mathjax so I'm just gonna draw it):
[image]

Where n is any integer from negative infinity to infinity, my idea is that the end product of this is tan(x). Is this even remotely correct or did I leave something out? Thanks!

(I do recognize that the horizontal asymptote is apparently 1 with this equation, but when I plot a section of this in desmos it seems to pass through y=1 anyway. There might be something going on that I could simplify in terms of rewriting an "x^2" somewhere, or maybe I'm just trippin.)

Comment: For convergence of a series, you would need the term goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  That fails here, I think.  Secondly, your series does not have the zeros $n\pi$.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good, but the series does not converge.

Actually, from the Mittag-Leffler's theorem (somewhat advanced complex analysis), one has the expansion
$$\tan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{8x}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2 - 4x^2}.$$
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem .)
Now the quadratic dependence of $n$ in the denominator ensure convergence!
Note that the above series correctly diverges at $x = (n+1/2)\pi$, and is zero at $x=n\pi$.

Comment: this does actually make a bit of sense when I bang my head against it. I definitely need to do more research on series, but i’m gonna wait until I finish precalc for that. Thank you!